# How to check class name exist in child div; of parent div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

How to check whether div Class within div class exist or not?

In following example; i want to check whether "showOnload" div class exist inside; parent div class "hideUnhidePanel"?

```
<div id="lodaDiv" hidden="true"  class="hideUnhidePanel">
  <div class="showOnload">
  </div>
  <div class="showOnload">
  </div>
  <div class="showOnload">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="load2Div" hidden="true"  class="hideUnhidePanel">
//Nothing exist
</div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$('.hideUnhidePanel').each(function() {
alert('yo');
if($(this).children('showOnload'))
alert('child exist');
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5h49x7qe/

**Update**:
Note -> In fiddle, it is displaying alert thrice; but in actual it should show two times only; as third showHidePanel does not have "showOnload" class.

Comment: I think it's already working in your jsfiddle

Comment: @Ketan

No; it is displaying alert thrice; but in actual it should show two times only as third showHidePanel does not have "showOnload" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.children() will always return a jQuery object, irrespective of whether one exists or not, so always it will be truthy. You can check the length of the jQuery object to see whether an element if present in the jQuery object or not.

Also you are missing the class selector `.` before `showOnload` in `children('showOnload')`

```js
$('.hideUnhidePanel').each(function() {
  snippet.log('yo: ' + this.id);
  if ($(this).children('.showOnload').length) {
    snippet.log('child exist');
  }

});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lodaDiv1" hidden="true" class="hideUnhidePanel">
  <div class="showOnload"></div>
  <div class="showOnload"></div>
  <div class="showOnload"></div>
</div>
<div id="lodaDiv2" hidden="true" class="hideUnhidePanel">
  <div class="showOnload"></div>
  <div class="showOnload"></div>
  <div class="showOnload"></div>
</div>
<div id="lodaDiv3" hidden="true" class="hideUnhidePanel"></div>
```

---

But if you want to iterate over only `hideUnhidePanel` with `showOnload` then you can use .has()/:has()

```js
$('.hideUnhidePanel').has('.showOnload').each(function() {
  //or $('.hideUnhidePanel:has(.showOnload)').each(function() {
  snippet.log('child exist: ' + this.id);
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="lodaDiv1" hidden="true" class="hideUnhidePanel">
  <div class="showOnload"></div>
  <div class="showOnload"></div>
  <div class="showOnload"></div>
</div>
<div id="lodaDiv2" hidden="true" class="hideUnhidePanel">
  <div class="showOnload"></div>
  <div class="showOnload"></div>
  <div class="showOnload"></div>
</div>
<div id="lodaDiv3" hidden="true" class="hideUnhidePanel"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. So if i have say some custom attribute in div class showonload like say data id = bank in all three child divs.......but i want to fetch  data id of one then i think this is good approach -> ... $(this).children('.showOnload').data("id")

Comment: @fatherazrael that should be fine.... it will always give the value of the first `showOnload` child of `this`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.parentClassName').each(function() {
  if ($(this).children('.childClassName').length) {
    //if child class found, Here write your code
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Shuvro. Sadly my project has gone now but your answer will help others. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

You can use searching class using "find()" and accordion-body is parents descensent use parent()

```
<div id="lodaDiv" hidden="true"  class="hideUnhidePanel">
      <div class="showOnload">
      </div>
      <div class="showOnload">
      </div>
      <div class="showOnload">
      </div>
    </div>

   $('.hideUnhidePanel').each(function() {

if($(this).parent().find('.showOnload').length)
{
alert($(this).parent().find('.showOnload').length+'child exist');
}
});
```

REF:https://jsfiddle.net/5ddf2vz8/3/

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution.

```
if($(".hideUnhidePanel .showOnload").length>0)
{
    alert("Child div with class .showOnload exists.);
}
else
{
    alert("Child div with class .showOnload do not exists.);
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ddf2vz8/6/)